# Admob banner request time

Tags: ios, objective-c, admob

I want to know if there is anyway to know when to refresh the ad banner to earn money from it?? and if there is a parameter that tell you when to do that?

please also show me how to refresh it using Objective-C

Comment: The banner will refresh automatically. You can set the refresh interval on AdMob.com.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, did'nt know that it was so easy!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Banner is updated automatically. Time you can set the console.
[image]
About the best time you [can read in this forum](http://forums.makingmoneywithandroid.com/advertising-networks/752-admob-banner-refresh-rate.html).

Comment: Thanks alot. This is outside topic, but can we earn from impressions only?? without clicks.?

Comment: I am afraid it is not.

Comment: If advertising will rarely click, as a result the get such a income one viewing.

Comment: Please explain more i dont quite understand what you meant

Comment: 1000 views. 1 click. Price click $0.15 . Price viewing = $0.15 / 1000

Comment: so we can earn $0.15 / 1000 from impressions only right??

Comment: It is approximately the numbers.